# How to concatenate two array format to Json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 input fields and one dynamic table, i created a json format when user enterd data, my problem is its comes 2 arrays, one array is that 5 input fields data and another one array is dynamic table data. but i want single array It means example json format given below.

how can i merge that two jsons?

Please refer my fiddle and check console..

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/w8xz6Ler/)**

I want json look like,

```
I want json like

$('form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = {
    "voucNum": $('#vocNum').val(),
    "vochDate": $('#vochDate').val(),
    "refno": $('#cashref').val(),
    "billtype": $('#cashbill').val(),
    "acctname": $('#cashAc').val(),
    "tds": $('#cashTds').val(),
    "total": $('#totaldbt').val(),
    "amount": $('#cashAmt').val(),
    "availableamt": $('#cash_bal').val(),
    "acctname": $('#payacc').val(),
    "cashpayment": [{
            "narr": $('#pay_narrat').val(),
            "acctcode": $('#payacc_code').val(),
            "debit": $('#paydeb').val(),
            "actname": $('#payacc').val(),
            "credit": $('#paycredit').val()
        },
        {
            "narr": $('#acc_narrat').val(),
            "acctcode": $('#cashAcctcode').val(),
            "debit": $('#cashdeb').val(),
            "accountName": $('#accountName').val(),
            "credit": $('#crditCash').val()
        }
    ]
}
console.log(data);
});
```

> Here is my Actual code

```js
// Table dynamic with Json format

var status;
var sno = [];
var load;
var no_rows = 0;
var row;

function submitVal() {
  var mainArr = [];
  var tmpArr = [];
  var mainTable = $('#tab_logic');
  var tr = mainTable.find('tbody tr');
  console.log(tr.length)
  tr.each(function() {
    tmpArr = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      //get attr id
      let title = $(this).find('input, selet').attr('id');

      var values = $(this).find('input, select').val();

      //input json format
      let pushing = $.parseJSON('{ "' + title + '": "' + values + '" }');

      tmpArr.push(pushing);

    });
    mainArr.push(tmpArr);
  });
  console.log(mainArr);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_Row").click(function() {
    row = `<tr id="tasklist" class="jsrow"><td><input type="text" class="sno sel_text form-control" placeholder="A/c code" id=""cashAcctcode name="acctcode"></input></td><td><select class="sel_sel form-control status" for="accountName" id="accountName" name="accountName"><option value="">Choose an items</option><option value="acc1">Account 1</option><option value="acc2">Account 2</option><option value="acc3">Account 3</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control pname" placeholder='Enter your text here' name="narr" id='acc_narrat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#accnarratModal'></input></td><td><input type="text" placeholder='Debit Amount' class='form-control task input-md' for="debit" name="debit" id='cashdeb' data-action='sumDebit'></input></td><td><input type="text" placeholder='Credit Amount' data-action='sumCredit' class='form-control comment input-md' name="credit" for="credit" id="crditCash" readonly></input></td><td><a class="dlt-icon"><button type="button" class="adRow" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td></tr>`;
    $("table > tbody").append(row);
    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.dlt-icon', function() {
      $(this).parents('tr.jsrow').first().remove();
    });
    bindScript();
  });

  $('form').submit(function() {
    submitVal();
  });
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function() {

    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
      if (o[this.name]) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
          o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
      } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
      }
    });
    return o;
  };
})(jQuery);

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {
    "voucNum": $('#vocNum').val(),
    "vochDate": $('#vochDate').val(),
    "refno": $('#cashref').val(),
    "billtype": $('#cashbill').val(),
    "acctname": $('#cashAc').val(),
    "tds": $('#cashTds').val(),
    "total": $('#totaldbt').val(),
    "amount": $('#cashAmt').val(),
    "availableamt": $('#cash_bal').val(),
    "acctname": $('#payacc').val(),
    "cashpayment": [{
        "narr": $('#pay_narrat').val(),
        "acctcode": $('#payacc_code').val(),
        "debit": $('#paydeb').val(),
        "actname": $('#payacc').val(),
        "credit": $('#paycredit').val()
      },
      {
        "narr": $('#acc_narrat').val(),
        "acctcode": $('#cashAcctcode').val(),
        "debit": $('#cashdeb').val(),
        "accountName": $('#accountName').val(),
        "credit": $('#crditCash').val()
      }
    ]
  };
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contactForm">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- voucher number -->

    <div class="col-4">
      <label class="col-sm-8 control-label p-sm-0" for="vouchno">Voucher Number :</label>
      <input type="number" id="vocNum" value="1" class="form-control vocnum-box" name="vouchno" readonly />
    </div>

    <!-- voucher date -->

    <div class="form-group col-3 rfdate">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label p-sm-0" for="vouchdt">Voucher Date :</label>
      <div class="input-group vcdate datepic" id="vocdate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vochDate" name="vouchdt" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Reference number -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0" for="RefNumber">Ref Number :</label>
      <input type="number" id="cashref" placeholder="Optional" class="form-control" name="refno" />
    </div>

    <!-- Bill type -->

    <div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0" for="billType">Bill type :</label>
      <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="billtype" id="cashbill" required>
        <option value="null">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="Raw">Raw Materials</option>
        <option value="Spare">Spare</option>
        <option id="othr_bill" value="Other">Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- refer date -->

    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0" for="refDate">Ref Date :</label>
      <div class="input-group date datepic" id="referdate">
        <input type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yy" class="form-control" name="referdate" id="refdate" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- cash account dropdown -->
    <div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0 input-group" for="acctcode">Cash Account :</label>
      <select class="form-control selectsch_items status" name="acctname" id="cashAc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="acc1">Account 1</option>
        <option value="acc2">Account 2</option>
        <option value="acc3">Account 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- TDS Field -->

    <div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" id="tds_tx">
      <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0" for="tds">TDS :</label>
      <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="tds" id="cashTds" required>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Amount field -->

    <div class="form-group col-3 amt_wid" id="amt_cash">
      <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0" for="amount">Amount :</label>
      <input type="number" id="cashAmt" placeholder="Enter Amount Here" class="form-control" name="amount" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- Cash payment Table -->
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
          <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
              <th class="text-center">
                Account Code
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                A/c Name*
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Narration*
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Debit*
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Credit
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Action
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="mainBody">
            <tr id="fst_row">
              <td>
                <input type="number" id="payacc_code" placeholder='Enter A/c code' for="acctcode" name="acctcode" class="form-control sel_text" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control sel_sel" id="payacc" name="actname" for="actname">
                  <option value="">Select TDS A/c name</option>
                  <option value="1">TDS A/c 1</option>
                  <option value="2">TDS A/c 2</option>
                  <option value="3">TDS A/c 3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pay_narrat" name="narr" for="narr" placeholder="Enter your text here" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="number" id="paydeb" value="100" name="debit" for="debit" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="number" id="paycredit" name="credit" for="credit" placeholder='Credit Amount' data-action="sumCredit" class="form-control" readonly />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <input type="button" class="add_Row adRow button-add" id="add_row" value="Add Row">
            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- total debit and credit field -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="cashTotal">
        <p class="tableTotal">Total:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input type="number" class="totaldeb" id="totaldbt" name="total" placeholder="Total Debit Amount" readonly>
      <input type="number" class="totalcredit" id="creditTotal" name="totalcredit" placeholder=" Total Credit Amount" value="200" style="margin-left: 8px;" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- available amount field -->

  <div class="form-group col-12">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-12 p-sm-0">
      <label class="col-sm-8 control-label p-sm-0">Available Amount :</label>
      <div class="cash-avail">
        <input type="text" value="dr" placeholder="Dr" class="form-control stc_accode" name="cash_dr" id="cash_dr" readonly />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Available Amount" class="form-control stc_subcode" name="availableamt" id="cash_bal" for="availableamt" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Submit Button -->

  <div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn load" id="cashSub">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Too much extraneous details. From the title, the question should basically contain code where you process the arrays and json data using JavaScript. BTW... Have you tried doing the concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to understand what you meant.

So you needed to merge two arrays: `mainArr` and `tempArr`, and instead of using `concat` you used `push` function that leads to the resulting array be an array with multiple arrays.

Just Replace,

```
mainArr.push(tmpArr);
```

to

```
mainArr = mainArr.concat(tmpArr);
```

> I know, its a delayed answer and may be you had already fixed the issue. But
>   if it helps :)